# Read "LocalConfiguration" in TYPO3 6.1 - ViewHelper

Tags: typo3, view-helpers

i want to read some data from the LocalConfiguration.
I don't found a way for fluid and for an ViewHelper.

I hope everyone can help me. 
Thanks! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From experience I have learned that you should NOT use the class `TYPO3\CMS\Core\Configuration\ConfigurationManager`. It is considered internal and may not return the actual configuration (disregarding settings done in `AdditionalConfiguration.php`). See for example the discussion [here](https://forge.typo3.org/issues/60650).

Instead, access the data using the variable `$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']`, e.g. use

```
echo $GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['DB']['username'].
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok - i have found a solution to read the LocalConfiguration File from TYPO3 with an ViewHelper.

```
$localConf = $this->objectManager->get('TYPO3\\CMS\\Core\\Configuration\\ConfigurationManager');

//Get Debug:
\TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Utility\DebuggerUtility::var_dump($localConf->getLocalConfiguration());
```

Now you have the complete LocalConf. Array.

Comment: Don't use `TYPO3\CMS\Core\Configuration\ConfigurationManager`, see my answer.